# Jackson Deserialize JSON To List of Different Types Depending On String Value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to deserialize a JSON string using Jackson into Lists of different Object types depending on the value set in one of the fields. I want to know what the best approach is for creating the different List Types and how i can implement this?

My JSON's would look something like this:

```
{"test":
    {"conditions":[....],                   
     "consequence": {"actionType":"string", 
                     "action": ["value 1","value 2"]}                                               
    }       
}
```

So when parsed the above would return a `List<String>`

```
{"test":
    {"conditions":[....],                   
     "consequence": {"actionType":"test", 
                     "action": ["test","test"]}                                             
    }       
}
```

and the above would return a `List<Test>`

My Pojo just contains:

```
  @Data
public class Consequence {

    public Consequence(String actionType){
        this.actionType = actionType;       
    };

    @JsonProperty("ACTIONTYPE")
    private String actionType;

    @JsonProperty("ACTION")
    private List<????> action;
}
```

UPDATE:

After i updated my POJO's using the following hierarchy:

```
@Data
public abstract class BaseConsequence {

    public BaseConsequence(String actionType){
        this.actionType = actionType;       
    };

    @JsonProperty("ACTIONTYPE")
    private String actionType;

}

 @Data
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "CONCATENATE")
public class ConcatenateConsequence extends BaseConsequence {

    public ConcatenateConsequence(String actionType, List<String> concatenateValues) {
        super(actionType);
        this.concatenateValues = concatenateValues;
    }
    private List<String> concatenateValues;
}

@Data
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "test")
public class TestConsequence extends BaseConsequence {

    public TestConsequence(String actionType, List<Test> tests){
        super(actionType);
        this.tests = tests;
    }
    private List<Test> tests;
}

@Data
public class Test {

    public Test(){};

    public Test(List<Condition> conditions, BaseConsequence baseConsequence){
        this.conditions = conditions;
        this.baseConsequence = baseConsequence;     
    }

    @JsonProperty("CONDITIONS")
    private List<Condition> conditions;

    @JsonProperty("CONSEQUENCE")
    private BaseConsequence baseConsequence;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (o == this) return true;

        if (!(o instanceof Test)) {
            return false;
        }        
        Test test = (Test) o;
        return Objects.equals(conditions, test.conditions) && Objects.equals(baseConsequence, test.baseConsequence);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(conditions, baseConsequence);
    }   
}
```

I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: {"TEST":{"CONDITIONS":[{"KEY":"KEY1","VALUES":["FLOAT"],"OPERATOR":""}],"CONSEQUENCE":{"ACTIONTYPE" :{"CONCATENATE": ["VALUE1","VALUE2"]}}}}; line: 1, column: 9] (through reference chain: package.TestCase["TEST"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two variants you can use:

1. Create custom deserializer. See here for full descriptions and examples http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization
2. The best way is to use one base class and two children. Each children should be marked with `@DiscriminatorValue`. See here for full description and examples http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Comment: Thank you oleg, i'll check out the options and see if i can implement one

Comment: Oleg, if i implement a custom deserializer do i need to check my attribute called "actionType" in the overwritten deserialize method and return the appropriate List Type in there?

Comment: Yes. In you deserializer you have access to json part. First you have to read your *key field* and then construct one object with specific data, or create dirrefernt objects depend on it. This is very powerful feature, but I strongly reccomend to look at `@DiscriminatorValue`.

Comment: I updated my Pojo's as suggested using the `@DiscriminatorValue` annotation from `javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue`. Can you take a look at the above and see if classes and use of the disciminator looks correct?

Comment: @Orby one question, can you modify your JSON or not?

Comment: Yes, i can change it to fit the use cases above

Comment: In case you return `List<String>`, `conditions` field should be ignored?

Comment: I changed my JSON to include an ACTION parameter: `{"test":{"conditions":[{"KEY":"KEY1","VALUES":["FLOAT"],"OPERATOR":""}],"CONSEQUENCE":{"ACTIONTYPE" :"CONCATENATE","ACTION": ["VALUE1","VALUE2"]}}}` and annotated my `private List<String> concatenateValues` and `private List<Test> tests` values with `@JsonProperty("ACTION")` but i'm still getting the same error. Is the problem to do with the way i'm referencing `private BaseConsequence baseConsequence` in my test class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155312/discussion-between-oleg-cherednik-and-orby).